# C# Trouble managing Lists in classes

Tags: c#

Good evening,

Just to have a little context, I started C# just a few months ago and I am making a bank application with C# as an assignment.

I have 2 classes: *Customer* and *Bank Employee* that inherit from the abstract class *Person*. The *Account* class (basically savings, current, whatever) inherits from the Customer class.

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYLUX.png)
I only kept the attributes because the rest doesn't matter for what's to follow.
My problem is that i can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong with the *AllAccounts* list regrouping all the Accounts from the Customer.

Here is the thing, i mostly manipulate the *AllAccounts*  list inside the Customer class and as soon as it's out of whatever method it was, it doesn't save any changes.

I checked by displaying the length of the list inside the method and outside of it (let it be in program.cs or Customer.cs). By default, the method creates 2 accounts so the first number displayed is **2**. However the second number displayed is **0** and this is where I am lost.

For example, I have this method `public Customer CreateCustomer()` that returns a Customer class, the first line i would write is `AllAccounts = new List<Account>();`. I later found out that it wasn't working, I then decided to initialise the list in a constructor.

```
public Customer()
        {
            AllAccounts = new List<Account>();
        }
```

It was still not keeping whatever changes i made to the *AllAccounts* list.

My latest attempt was to initialise *AllAccounts* list inside the main, which gave me an null error when trying to display the length.

I'd like to understand What I am missing and where I am wrong.

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**:

Here are my attributes for Customer, the constructor and the CreateCustomer method:

Customer.cs

```
        private int pinNumber { get; set; }
        private string accountNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Account> AllAccounts { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            AllAccounts = new List<Account>();
        }

        public Customer CreateCustomer()
        {
            string full = "accountnumber"; // Just a login thing, dont mind
            int pin = 1; // same here
            string path = "Customers";
            string saving = path + "\\saving.txt";
            string current = path + "\\current.txt";
            AllAccounts.Add(new Account() { path = saving, name = "saving", total = 0 });
            AllAccounts.Add(new Account() { path = current, name = "current", total = 0 });
            return new Customer() { firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName, pinNumber = pin, accountNumber = full };
        }
```

Inside program.cs, that's how I call the createcustomer method:

```
var Client = new Customer();
//get client info
AllCustomers.Add(Client.CreateCustomer());
```

After adding my customer to* AllCustomers*, the firstname, lastname are saved but not what was on *AllAccounts*.

When i run this:

```
Console.WriteLine(AllCustomers[0].AllAccounts[0].name);
```

It displays null basically, not even an error is shown it's just a null character.

By the way thanks for your replies!

Comment: Why would Account inherit from Customer? That doesn't make any sense. How is an Account a type of Customer? It isn't. Customer can have accounts, but accounts are not a type of customer. Beyond that I need to see more of your code, there isn't enough here for me to help you. Post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Are you able to post more code i.e. where are you trying to access `AllAccounts`?

Comment: No one will be able to give you an answer unless you show the rest of the code you are talking about.

Comment: Hey, @DetectivePikachu you are absolutely right, having Account inherit from Customer is dumb. Thanks for clarifying !.

Comment: Happy to help, we have all been there. Just another suggestion now that I have seen your code -- Everything in "CreateCustomer" should just be moved into the constructor except the `return` line. Delete that method. Having a Customer create instances of itself makes a pseudo-factory which is an anti-pattern. Just delete that method, move its code into the constructor and then change the the Add customer call to `AllCustomers.Add(new Customer());` A customer shouldn't be responsible for making other customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the Issue is when you are returning `new Customer()` in `CreateCustomer()`. You are not passing the list which was created by `CreateCustomer()`.

```
return new Customer() { firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName, pinNumber = pin, accountNumber = full,AllAccounts=AllAccounts };
```

So, right now you create a new `Account list` but its basically not being assigned to the customer, hence no account to any customer and once you create a new Customer, because of the constructor initializing of the `new Account List` all the previous data is lost.

Update your return statement and it would work

Comment: Hi, I can't believe it was a simple as that and it actually works ! Thank you

Comment: No Worries, Happy Coding!